# While Loop is not working well with the time

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, date, time

I have a code with this ↓ part in it, which should do something when the time and day come. It has `outer` and `inner` time and day checks (`while loops`).
`Outer` for the situation in which code starts processing in time (or day) which is not in the `timerange` for code processing - it `should` wait until that time (or day). And it works, but only in situation when I set it like 10 minutes before the `timerange` (code processing time). When I set it like a night before, it won't works and it stops in `print("timerange wait")` It shows False even it should be True. Is there a problem because it is not in the same day? Or something else? Please give me some advices.

Here is the simple version of code (without unnecessary parts )

```py
import os
import datetime
from time import sleep
from datetime import date



#setting used variables
now = datetime.datetime.now()
morning = now.replace(hour=8, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
evening = now.replace(hour=18, minute=9, second=0, microsecond=0)


# function for check creating "timerange -start time, end time"
def time_in_range(morning, evening, x):
    if morning <= evening:
        return morning <= x <= evening
    else:
        return morning <= x or x <= evening


# main program for doing something
def main():
    while True:
# Time period check - Check if time and weekdays are not out of range
# if not in range will wait till the time
        if date.today().weekday():
            dayz = True
        else:
            dayz = False
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        timerange = time_in_range(morning, evening, now)
        if timerange != True:
            print("waiting for function-time")
            sleep(10)
            continue
        if dayz != True:
            print("waiting for function-days")
            sleep(3600)
            continue

        while True:
            print("do something")
#check if during while loop there wasn't date, time change (out of timerange etc)
            if date.today().weekday():
                dayz = True
            else:
                dayz = False
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            timerange = time_in_range(morning, evening, now)
            if timerange != True:
                print("break inner loop-timerange")
                break
            if dayz != True:
                print("break inner loop-dayz")
                break
            print("do something -main work")



#program starts here        
timerange = time_in_range(morning, evening, now)


# check if today is weekday (outer loop)
if date.today().weekday():
    dayz = True
else:
    dayz = False

# if today is not a weekday wait till weekday (outer loop) 
#for situation where the code started not in weekday
while dayz != True:
    print("days wait")
    sleep(3600)
    dayz = date.today().weekday()
    if dayz == True:
        break
# If it is not processing time, wait until it becomes
# for the situation where code started not in "timerange"
while timerange != True:
    print("timerange wait") # ---------HERE IT STOPS---------
# But it works fine, when I set it like one hour before 'timerange' or so...
    sleep(10)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timerange = time_in_range(morning, evening, now)
    print(timerange)
    if timerange == True:
        break

# Do the main function
main()

# Let know when code ends
print("Over of Code")
```

Comment: You use of the `weekday()` method looks suspicious. According to the documentation it "Returns the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6", so testing the "truthiness" of its return value is testing whether the given date is a not a Monday.

Comment: @martineau thanks for the suggestion! Im going to check it. What are you think about that "timerange"? Why it works as True only if I starts the program in the same day which it should execute?